# Is there a mechanism to run a "service" by a non-root user?

Tags: rhel, non-root-user, daemon

Is there a way I can have a continuously running, background process that can be controlled by me (a regular, non-root user)?

All I need to be able to do is start, stop and restart the process. Monitoring by PID and sending SIGHUP or SIGINT for termination is fine. I'm okay with using a complicated bash script, it doesn't have to be something system-wide. Just for me.

I also really need it to not stop when I log off from ssh.

Is there a way I can do this in RHEL 6.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### screen or tmux

Sure you can start processes and have then run continuously by making use of a terminal multiplexer such as screen or tmux. Processes can continue to persist in a screen or tmux session, and you can connect/disconnect to either (screen or tmux) as needed.

#### backgrounding

You can run any process you like and then background it and then disconnect it from your current terminal using the command `disown`.

```
$ disown -a
```

Additionally if you just want to start a process up and not have to background it and `disown` it you can use the command `nohup`.

```
$ nohup myexec &
```

When you exit the shell, `myexec` will continue to be running.

#### Example

Start a fake process.

```
$ sleep 12345 &
[1] 24339
$
```

Make sure we can see it:

```
$ pgrep -f "sleep 12345"
24339
```

But it's still connected to our terminal:

```
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sleep 12345 &
```

So let's `disown` it:

```
$ disown -a
$ jobs
$
```

See it's still running:

```
$ pgrep -f "sleep 12345"
24339
```

Now let's log out, and log back in. See it's still there:

```
$ pgrep -f "sleep 12345"
24339
```

You can kill this process any time using standard means:

```
$ pkill -HUP -f "sleep 12345"
$ pgrep -f "sleep 12345"
$
```

The above will send the signal `HUP` to a process name matching the pattern "sleep 12345". Double checking shows that it's now gone.